# React Navigation V2 Hide Single Tab From Bottom Tab Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a React Native app. When the user loads the app, I want the first screen they see to be a Home screen to tell them about some of the features of the app. Currently, I am using a BottomTabNavigator with nested StackNavigators inside. I have been able to get my Home screen added, but it always shows up the in TabNavigator. Is there a way to make a single tab item not present in any of the screens?

PS. I have tried using a StackNavigator as my parent like the following, but my TabNavigator does not show up:

```
const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Item1: Item1,
    Item2: Item2,
    Item3: Item3, 
    Item4: Item4,
    Item5: Item5
});

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: Home,
    Content: AppNavigator
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

If I have screens called **Item1**, **Item2**, **Item3**, **Item4**, **Item5**, and **Home**, I want to make it display **Home** first. In addition, I want the TabBar visible at the bottom, but it can't include the **Home** screen.

Comment: I am not able to get it clearly, What do you mean by 'single tab item not present in any of the screens' ? Can you elaborate little bit

Comment: @YogarajSaravanan I updated the question above to have a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to nest your main app tab navigator inside another tab navigator  like this:

```js
const AppNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Main: { screen: MainScreen },
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
});

export default TabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    App: { screen: AppNavigator },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarVisible: false,
    }),
  }
);
```

Comment: This is close, but it does not show the App Tab Navigator.

Comment: I'm not sure where you want the tab navigator?  There is one on the main screen but not the home screen correct?

Comment: I want the navigator to display on all screen. I just want the Home screen to never display on the Tab Navigator.

Comment: A tab bar by it's very nature will always have an **active** tab.  So you have to first work out what tab you want to be active when the "Home" content is displayed.  If that is "Item 1" you need some conditional logic inside the screen for Item 1 that either shows the "Home" content or the "Item 1" content.

Answer (score 0):

I think SwitchNavigator is what do you need https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html. Try like this

```
const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Home: Home,
    Content: AppNavigator
}
```

If you want TabNavigator you can simply do the same

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: Home,
    Content: AppNavigator
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but the bottom TabBar is not visible.

Comment: This ends up showing the Parent TabBar not the Child TabBar. Think about this. I want a landing page that they are never going to be able to get back to. It will display once they open the app, but they will not be able to navigate back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom tabBarComponent for your Tab Navigator to use.

Map through the routes in that custom tabBarComponent and don't render anything for that Tab if `route.routeName === 'Home'`.

```
const TabBar = props => {
  return (
      {navigation.state.routes.map((route, i) => {
          if (route.routeName !== 'Home') {
          return (
              <Tab...
```